# Unwanted browswer redirection

Tags: windows, malware, internet-explorer

I use IE 10 on Windows 10, and when I type www.outlook.com, my Facebook page opens! I can type www.msn.com and use it to get to the email, but what is causing this and how to fix it? I tried several malware checkers, no good. Thanks.

Comment: Did you empty your caches?

Comment: When you ping www.outlook.com does it go to the correct IP address? If not  then you need to determine where your system is getting the bad DNS info from. Check local /etc/hosts (or equivalent first), this see what your local DNS server thinks the correct resolution is. If it's not a DNS issue (ping goes to the correct address) check for browser plugins.

Comment: @Arminius, good idea.

Comment: @TreyBlalock, I pinged the outlook, and got the ip address of Microsoft, so where is Facebook redirection coming from then? Maybe I should clear the buffers first.

Comment: Try a second browser like Chrome or Opera to rule out a problem with an upstream proxy then debug your browser.

Comment: It worked with Chrome. I mean I got the correct outlook page when I typed the address. Not the same case as with IE.